# Error 1 error C3867: 'Command::getSecondWord': function call missing argument list; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm really close to finishing my project, but i'm running into an error that I just can't wrap my head around.

It's telling me to use & sign to create a pointer to member.

```
void Inventory::eat(string food){
//takes in the string stores it in temp string  call isitemin inventory to return an int
//use that int to return isEdible, int = 2 means your checking at pos 2
//if edible remove from inventory and add 2hp
string tempString = food;
int checker=isItemInventory(tempString);
bool edible = inventory[checker].getEdible;
if (!edible){
    cout << "you can't eat " + food << endl;
}
else//ended here for now
```

So basically i have an eat function that takes in a string, it stores the string in tempstring and then uses isItemInventory() to return a number. This number tells us where abouts in the vector "inventory" that the item were trying to eat is located. Once we have that number we create a local boolean and call getEdible on the item. this should return true or false but instead i'm getting an error about using a pointer ? can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want:

```
bool edible = inventory[checker].getEdible();
                                       // ^^ parentheses are needed to call a function
```

Comment: and this is why I should take breaks every few hours :/ thanks dude!